# Compute Maximum likelihood of a function which is defined only in the L1 norm

Tags: optimization, normed-spaces, maximum-likelihood, parameter-estimation

if $x \in\mathbb R^2$ and

$$
f_\theta(x)=
    \begin{cases}
        \frac{1}{2\theta^2}  & \text{if } \|x\|_1 \le \theta  \\
        0 & \text{otherwise.}
    \end{cases}
$$

Find the maximum likelihood estimate of $\theta$.

this is what I did:

1- Compute $L(\theta) = \prod_{i=1}^n = \frac{1}{2^n(\theta^2)^n}$

2 - Compute $\ell(\theta) = \ln L(\theta) = -n\ln(2)-2n\ln(\theta)$

3 - derive and = $0$
But when I do it, I get $\frac{-2n}{\theta}=0$ which doesn't work.

Can someone please guide me and tell me where I am mistaken?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In step (1), you should have $$L(\theta;\mathbf{x}) = \begin{cases}1/(2^n \theta^{2n}), & \text{if } \max(\|x_i\|_1 : 1 \leq i \leq n) \leq \theta \\ 0, & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Then the maximum occurs when $\theta$ is minimized in the first case, so $$\hat\theta_{\text{MLE}} = \max(\|x_i\|_1 : 1 \leq i \leq n)$$

Comment: I am sorry but I am not sure to understand?

Comment: @lalaland In short, you cannot ignore the "otherwise" case in the definition of $f_\theta(x)$.  Doing so makes your likelihood function incorrect.

Comment: Yes, you are right. but in your answer, it as if $ \theta$ depends on x. but I see it in the opposite way.

Comment: The MLE estimate for $\theta$ is a function of the data $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n$, so it does depend on the data by definition.  Whether or not $\theta$ itself depends on $x$ doesn't matter here (and there's certainly not enough room in this comment thread to debate whether the Bayesians are correct)

Comment: @lalaland: I often find myself scratching my brain over these kinds of problems too. Here is how I handled it. Supposed we observed a sample of size $n=2$ to be $x_1=(1,2)$ and $x_2=(-1,3)$. Define $$g(\theta)=f_{\theta}(x_1)f_{\theta}(x_2)$$ Note $g(\theta)=\Big(\frac{1}{2\theta^2}\Big)^2$ whenever $\theta \geq 4=\max\{||x_1||_1,||x_2||_1\}$ and $g(\theta)=0$ otherwise. Can you see how $g$ is maximized whenever $\theta=4$?

Comment: @MatthewHolder Yeah Thank you so much for this clarification. I appreciate it

Comment: @BrianMoehring Thanks for the explanation! even though I needed MatthewHolder help. Thanks, guys

Comment: No problem. I highly recommend you always refer to a specific example whenever you're not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Thanks @MatthewHolder

Answer (score 2):

You should unlearn the idea that the MLE of $\theta$ is the point at which $(d/d\theta) \ln L(\theta) = 0.$

A point at which the derivative is $0$ is not the same as a point at which the function is maximized. In **some** cases there will be a unique point at which the derivative is $0$ and that will be the unique global maximum point, but you should understand what you're doing before you rely on that.

In some cases (including this one) a maximum occurs at an endpoint of the domain of the function, and at an endpoint maximum the derivative is not generally $0.$

The domain is $\big[\|x\|_1, +\infty)$ and the function increases as $\theta$ decreases. Therefore the maximum is at $\theta=\|x\|_1.$

**PS:** This is the MLE if there is just one observed vector $x.$

Comment: +1 for your first line.  I've run into too many students who want a single concise algorithm for these applications, and they completely ignore the arguably more concise definition.

Comment: @BrianMoehring : The de-facto school curriculum pounds into everyone's head the idea that learning mathematics consists of memorizing and applying algorithms. $99.9\%$ of students have never suspected that there's anything else.

Comment: I am just curious, if there was an outlier, $\theta$ would be badly estimated, right?

Comment: @MichaelHardy      can you please see above?

Comment: @lalaland : The only was the estimate would be very badly off is if _every_ observation had an improbably small value of $\|x\|_1. \qquad$